# history.push() updates url but does not render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history.js

When I try to navigate trougth my project history seems to not work to render other components.

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './components/Login.jsx';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Apuntes from './components/Apuntes';
import history from './history/history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
      <Route exact path='/apuntes' component={Apuntes} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Then in my login class I call the history.push('/apuntes') and it changes the url but does nothing more.
The history.js is this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

I would like to know how to fix this and get it to show the component depending the url.

Comment: Share your login class please

Comment: also show how are you calling history.push() method

Comment: I might be wrong but `export default createBrowserHistory()` is creating a new instance every time it's imported. Try changing it to `const history = createBrowserHistory ()` and export it

Answer (score 0):

this will work :)

```
//import your components here 
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
export function App() {
const history = useHistory();
if (true) { // any condition you need here
   history.push("/login");
return (
  <Switch>     
  <Router>
    <Route exact path='/login'><Login/></Route>
    <Route exact path='/register'><Register/></Route>
    <Route exact path='/apuntes'><Apuntes/></Route>
  </Router>
</Switch>
);
}
```

plus you can define a route as default by adding this route at the end of routes.

```
  <Route path="/">
    <YourDefaultComponent/>
  </Route>
```